# Countable basis of measure intuition

Tags: measure-theory

I have been through a measure and integration theory course. We adopted the book Introduction to Measure and Integration by Taylor. We have not covered chapter 8 whose title is Linear Functionals. I wanted to go through that chapter as way to motivate myself for functional analysis. I got stuck on the following concept of countable basis of measure.

*If we have a measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ we say that $\mu$ has a countable basis if there is a sequence $\{E_n\}$ of sets in $\mathscr{F}$ such that, given $\epsilon>0$ and any $A\in\mathscr{F}$ with $\mu{A}\leqslant\infty$, there is a set $E_k$ of the sequence for which $\mu(A\Delta E_k)<\epsilon$*

However dow on the page the it follows the next:
 **Lemma: A measure $\mu$ has countable basis if and only if , for each $\epsilon>0$, any collection $\mathscr{C}\subset\mathscr{F}$ of subsets of finite measure such that $A,B\in\mathscr{C},\:\:\:A\neq B\rightarrow\mu(A\Delta B)\geqslant\epsilon$(1) is countable.**

*Proof. Suppose first that $\epsilon>0$ is such that there is a non-countable $\mathscr{C}$ satisfying (1); and suppose if possible that $\mu$ has countable basis $\mathscr{D}$. Then, for each $A\in\mathscr{C}$ we can find a set $E_A\in\mathscr{D}$ with $\mu(A\Delta E_A)<\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$
Then if $A\neq B$,
$\mu(E_A\Delta E_B)\geqslant\mu(A\Delta B)-\mu(A\Delta E_A)-\mu(B\Delta E_B)>\frac{1}{3}\epsilon>0$
so that $E_A\neq E_B$.Thus if $\mathscr{D}$ is dense, it contains a non-countable subclass, which is a contradiction.*

(1) What is the intuition behind the contable basis of a measure?

(2)I do not understand the proof of the lemma. How do we get $\mu(E_A\Delta E_B)\geqslant\mu(A\Delta B)-\mu(A\Delta E_A)-\mu(B\Delta E_B)>\frac{1}{3}\epsilon>0$
?

(3)Why use $\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that $$\mu(E_A\Delta E_B)\geqslant\mu(A\Delta B)-\mu(A\Delta E_A)-\mu(B\Delta E_B)>\frac{1}{3}\epsilon>0$$ should be
$$\mu(E_A\Delta E_B)\geqslant\mu(A\Delta B)-\mu(A\Delta E_A)-\mu(B\Delta E_B)>\frac{1}{3}\epsilon+\frac{1}{3}\epsilon+\frac{1}{3}\epsilon = \epsilon > 0$$
That would explain the choice of $\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$.

Comment: You seem to be right, which means the book might have a mistake. I have just checked it out! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, now I see how it works. We have $\mu(A \Delta B) \geq \epsilon$, $\mu(A \Delta E_A) < \frac13\epsilon$ and $\mu(B \Delta E_B) < \frac13\epsilon$, so
$$\mu(A \Delta B) - \mu(A \Delta E_A) - \mu(B \Delta E_B) > \epsilon - \frac13\epsilon - \frac13\epsilon = \frac13\epsilon$$
The reason for the choice $\frac13\epsilon$ is to make the expression positive.